# Gray screen since updating to latest iOS 15 beta, Xcode warning _disableAlpha

Tags: swift, swiftui, foundation, xcode13, ios15

Since updating to the latest iOS 15 beta im getting just a gray screen when starting my app. Xcode (also latest beta) shows several times this message in the console since updating:

[Foundation] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: value for key (_disableAlpha) is not an object. This will become an error in the future.

The error is in the line with the GameScene displayed:

```
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Menu")
        return scene!
    }
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the grey box is due to transparency not being enabled when rendering the scene:

```
 SpriteView(scene: MyScene(), options: [.allowsTransparency])
```

.. but I'm also getting that error showing in iOS 15 beta, albeit not the grey box due to enabling transparency.